# Windows Backup Types

Tags: windows, windows-xp, backup, windows-backup

In reference to https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/types_of_backup.mspx?mfr=true

If I start a new task with a Incremental backup will it grab all my files and just add the changed files? Right now the daily backups are using Daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time incremental backup will make normal backup and each next time it will backup only files changed since last normal/incremental backup.